# reflection in HTML 5 ( Javascript )

Tags: html, reflection

Does JavaScript supports "Reflection" functionality? If yes, can you please provide me some basic example, which will help me to understand.

Comment: I think you are looking for ECMAScript 6 (ES6) not HTML5. Look for : Symbol, Reflect, and Proxy : http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reflection

Comment: Yeah, let me look into this.